# Satzzeichen in "frei lebenden Tieren, die dem Jagdrecht unterliegen, dem Wild"

Tags: punctuation

Aus [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildbret):

> Wildbret (auch Wildpret) (mhd. wildbræt „Fleisch vom Wild“) ist die Bezeichnung für Fleisch von **frei lebenden Tieren, die dem Jagdrecht unterliegen, dem Wild**.

Wie ich verstehe, ist "Wild" eine Beziechnung von "frei lebenden Tieren, die dem Jagdrecht unterliegen". Ist es nicht dann verwirrend, ein Komma da zu setzen? Sollte nicht eher ein Doppelpunkt verwendet werden?

> ... ist die Bezeichnung für Fleisch von **frei lebenden Tieren, die dem Jagdrecht unterliegen: das Wild**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dem gegebenen Satz

> … Fleisch von frei lebenden Tieren, die dem Jagdrecht unterliegen, dem Wild.

ist „dem Wild“ eine nachgetragene Apposition. Wenn so wie hier die nachgetragene Apposition zusammen mit einem Artikelwort folgt, steht sie laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* im gleichen Kasus wie der Bezugsausdruck:

> das Wirken dieses Mannes, eines mutigen Vorkämpfers
>
> nach Meinung des Parteivorsitzenden, des Bundesaußenministers Schulze, wurde …
>
> Man ernannte eine Frau zur Richterin am Supreme Court, einem Hort amerikanischer Männlichkeit.

Die nachgetragene Apposition wird gemäß § 77 (2) des [Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) mit einem Komma abgegrenzt.

> das Fleisch von frei lebenden Tieren, dem Wild

Wenn die Apposition eingeschoben ist, schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.

> das Fleisch von frei lebenden Tieren, dem Wild, schmeckt ihr nicht

Zur Abgrenzung kann man gemäß § 84 (2) auch Gedankenstriche

> das Fleisch von frei lebenden Tieren – dem Wild
>
> das Fleisch von frei lebenden Tieren – dem Wild – schmeckt ihr nicht

oder gemäß § 86 (2) Klammern verwenden.

> das Fleisch von frei lebenden Tieren (dem Wild)
>
> das Fleisch von frei lebenden Tieren (dem Wild) schmeckt ihr nicht